# Apple Memo recorder - Container & Elevated button or Container same size, can't do like apple memo recorder view

Tags: flutter, containers

I am trying to duplicate the Apple memo record interface, but I have an issue with the container. I have tried to use an other container & also elevated button but in both cases, the widget have the same size. I do not understand why.

[image]

```
Container _RecordButton(){

    return Container(
        height: 90,
        width: 90,
        decoration: BoxDecoration(
          border: Border.all(
            width: 4.0,
            color: Colors.grey,
          ),
          shape: BoxShape.circle,
        ),
      child: Container(

          child: _createElevatedButton()),);  //_RecordButton2()
  }


  Container _RecordButton2(){

    return Container(
          height: 15,
          width: 15,
      color: Colors.red,
    );
  }


  ElevatedButton _createElevatedButton(
      {IconData icon,  Function onPressFunc}) {
    return ElevatedButton(
        onPressed: () {},
        style: ButtonStyle(
        shape: MaterialStateProperty.all(CircleBorder()),
        padding: MaterialStateProperty.all(EdgeInsets.all(20)),
        backgroundColor: MaterialStateProperty.all(Colors.red), // <-- Button color

           ));
```

Answer (score 0):

it is so simple that I should have find it before. Here is the answer, it might help someone else.

```
Container _RecordButton(){

    return Container(
        height: 90,
        width: 90,
        decoration: BoxDecoration(
          border: Border.all(
            width: 4.0,
            color: Colors.grey,
          ),
          shape: BoxShape.circle,
        ),
      child: Padding(
          padding: EdgeInsets.all(4.0),
          child: _createElevatedButton()),);  //_RecordButton2()
  }
```